# Alternative formula for partial lookup within a list

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, vlookup, textjoin

I am looking for a alternative formula for this one:

```
index(Categories!$B$2:$B,match(1,search("*"&Categories!$B$2:$B&"*",$D2),0)))
```

This is a partial lookup formula where categories is in a range, though it is working, it is kinda slow, I am looking for some alternative that will not slow down my spreadsheet

sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yBG10G1InFk3tNyg8TpzI-HkAyuMBAsM6amVak2-tpI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: edited the post, sheet 1 is the conditions, and in sheet2 is where I want to show the result, highlighted cells is where the formula should go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(A2:A), "[a-z ]*")), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(Sheet1!A2:A), "[a-z ]*")))), 
 {TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(Sheet1!A2:A), "[a-z ]*")), Sheet1!B2:D}, {2, 3, 4}, 0)))
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(Sheet2!A2:A, "\(|\)|\*|\.|""|\-|\:", )), 
 "[a-z &@0-9]*")), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!A2:A, "\(|\)|\*|\.|""|\-|\:", )), 
 "[a-z &@0-9]*")))), {
 TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!A2:A, "\(|\)|\*|\.|""|\-|\:", )),
 "[a-z &@0-9]*")), Sheet1!B2:D}, {2, 3, 4}, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, this works well, but it only works when the condition is in the beginning of the string, though it was my fault, most of the examples that I provided are all at the beginning, but how am I able to modify this formula  if the condition is anywhere inside the cell?

Comment: @Mr.YJY well your dataset is very unfriendly to regex and characters like `* | . ` shouldn't be there coz those need to be escaped in regex syntax so you can try to remove them with SUBSTITUTE before they are passed to regex

Comment: those are from banks, and as you know, banks have this description which are not friendly in general. How should I do that?

Comment: Still the same, it only shows result if the condition is at the start of the string

Comment: I have updated the sheet with other example, I have also applies the latest formula that you gave

Comment: We can use helper column if needed, I just don't know how to properly do that.

Comment: @Mr.YJY answer updated

Comment: Thank you for this, it works perfectly, uhm, can I have a request? can you delete the first image? I didn't notice that I have included something that I shouldn't include in the sample, thank you very much